# Contraction of spring on passing current

Tags: electromagnetism

When a current is passed through a spring it contracts and it's potential energy increases . From where does this energy comes from ? Which agent does work? Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

The spring contracts because the turns, carrying currents in the same direction, attract each other. [There are other ways of explaining the contraction.]

The magnetic flux density will be greater in the contracted spring, as the number of turns per unit length has increased. [For a long solenoid carrying current $I$, the magnitude of the flux density in the central region is given by $B=\mu_{0} \nu I$ in which $\nu$ is the number of turns per unit length.

The self-produced magnetic flux linked with the solenoid will therefore increase as the solenoid contracts. According to Lenz's law a back-emf will therefore be induced in the solenoid while it contracts. The current will have to do work against this back emf, and the source of this work is the battery!

Comment: you wrote "There are other ways of explaining the contraction", what did you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking of the radial component of $\vec{B}$ at the end-regions of the solenoid. These exert motor effect axial forces on the end-turns of the solenoid. These forces are directed towards the centre of the solenoid. Not, I think, as nice a treatment as the attracting turns.

Comment: how would that explain the attractive forces between the loops of the solenoid that are in the middle?

Comment: It wouldn't. But the forces (towards the centre of the solenoid/spring) on the end-turns would squash the whole coil, would they not? [Just as if I pushed together the ends of the spring using my hands.]

Comment: that is true but your comment seems to imply that the force/displacement in the middle would be a result of the end forces and I think that is incorrect, instead  I believe that every winding has equal role in the total force.

Comment: So do I. That's why I said I thought this wasn't a nice treatment. It was, though, the first thing that came into my head when thinking about the original question. It would be delightful if the two treatments turned out to predict the same degree of contraction, but I don't think they do.

Comment: Ignoring all but nearest neighbours, the force between turns is roughly $\frac{\mu_{0} r I}{s}$ in which $s$ is the separation of centres of wire of neighbouring turns. Knowing that the axial flux density halves as we approach the ends of the solenoid, we can estimate the radial flux using $div \vec{B}=0$. This gave me, approximating wildly, a force of $\frac{\pi}{2} \mu_{0} \frac{r^2}{s^2} I^2 $ on the end turns taken together. Looks as if it might swamp the inter-turn force!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88390/discussion-between-philip-wood-and-hyportnex).